# Content cannot be displayed: Too many SOQL queries: 101 in VF page

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql

I am facing this error when I am refreshing my VF page. I know this is because SOQL query is written inside the for loops but I am struggling with removing the SOQL outside the for loop.

Here is the method which is called when constructor runs when the page loads

```
public List<selectedProductClass> getSelectedProductClassString(){


    List<List<String>> lstProductsInCategory = new List<List<String>>();
    lstAllAccountProductClassString = new List<selectedProductClass>();

    Map <List<String>,String> mapProductCategory = new Map <List<String>,String>();
    Map <List<String>,String> mapShow = new Map <List<String>,String>();


   for(Account_Product__c accProducts : [SELECT Id,Account__c,Product_Category__c,Show__c,Products__c from Account_Product__c where Account__c =: this.iAccountId]){

       for(String pd : accProducts.Products__c.split(';')) {
       selectedProductClass objClass = new selectedProductClass ();
            objClass.selectedShow = accProducts.Show__c ;
            objClass.selectedCategory = accProducts.Product_Category__c;
            objClass.selectProduct = pd;

       Product__c[] prod  = [SELECT Id from Product__c where  Name =:pd AND Product_Category__c =: accProducts.Product_Category__c AND Show__c =:accProducts.Show__c limit 1];
          if (prod.size() > 0)
            objClass.ProductId = prod[0].Id;
            lstAllAccountProductClassString.add(objClass); 
        }
           lstProductsInCategory.add(accProducts.Products__c.split(';'));
           mapProductCategory.put(accProducts.Products__c.split(';'),accProducts.Product_Category__c);
           mapShow.put(accProducts.Products__c.split(';'),accProducts.Show__c);
    }


    return lstAllAccountProductClassString;
}
```

Comment: seems like you are constucted map isnot proper.. using set you can collect the "accProducts.Show__c" and then use in product__c[]prod and same way for name also..

Comment: You should not perform SOQL/DML  inside FOR loop ever. It is not best practice as they could cross governor limits easily.

Comment: @AnnappaPH ok thats fine but how can i remove the soql query outside for loop

Comment: @Mr.Frodo I am struggling in removing soql query outside for loop

Comment: Read this [Salesforce Document](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Code_Best_Practices) on bulkification. It will be helpful.

Comment: I don't see why this has been down-voted. Avesh has provided his code, tried to solve the problem himself, asked a question with a clear answer. In fact, the answer is not so stunningly simple as the down-vote would imply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to gather all the requirements for your query on `Product__c` up-front, then query all the possible records you need from there before you enter the `for` loop. Like this:

```
public List<selectedProductClass> getSelectedProductClassString(){
    List<List<String>> lstProductsInCategory = new List<List<String>>();
    lstAllAccountProductClassString = new List<selectedProductClass>();

    Map <List<String>,String> mapProductCategory = new Map <List<String>,String>();
    Map <List<String>,String> mapShow = new Map <List<String>,String>();

    List<Account_Product__c> allAccProducts = [SELECT Id,Account__c,Product_Category__c,Show__c,Products__c from Account_Product__c where Account__c =: this.iAccountId];
    Set<String> allAccountProductNames = new Set<String>();
    Set<String> allProductCategories = new Set<String>();
    Set<String> allAccountProductShows = new Set<String>();

    for(Account_Product__c ap : allAccProducts) {
        allAccountProductNames.add(ap.split(';'));
        allProductCategories.add(ap.Product_Category__c);
        allAccountProductShows.add(ap.Show__c);
    }

    List<Product__c> allProducts =  [
            SELECT Id 
            from Product__c 
            where  Name IN :allAccountProductNames 
            AND Product_Category__c IN :allProductCategories 
            AND Show__c IN :allAccountProductShows];

    for(Account_Product__c accProducts : allAccProducts){

        for(String pd : accProducts.Products__c.split(';')) {
            selectedProductClass objClass = new selectedProductClass ();
            objClass.selectedShow = accProducts.Show__c ;
            objClass.selectedCategory = accProducts.Product_Category__c;
            objClass.selectProduct = pd;

            //TODO Find whether or not accProducts matches a record in allProducts
        }
        lstProductsInCategory.add(accProducts.Products__c.split(';'));
        mapProductCategory.put(accProducts.Products__c.split(';'),accProducts.Product_Category__c);
        mapShow.put(accProducts.Products__c.split(';'),accProducts.Show__c);
    }


    return lstAllAccountProductClassString;
}
```

The part which is tricky to do well is the bit I've left as `TODO`. If there is a matching `Product__c`, it will be in `allProducts`. If performance is not important, then you could just loop through that whole list. If it is important, you might need to use some maps to get faster access, but that's beyond the scope of your original question.

Comment: Appreciate your help the below code also worked for me.

Comment: Please make it as @Aidan answer as best answer ....Please close the Post